# PHP - Displaying html from mysql text field in a div

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've some problem with displaying html tags after I retrieve them from a text field in my mysql DB.

my code looks something like this:

```
<div class='textDiv'><? echo htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $row["textField"]), ENT_NOQUOTES);?></div>
```

So when the text field in mysql has only plain text, everything is fine, but when I add a link inside the text, I get a line break before and after the link tag, and the displayed text becomes line this:

```
Some text justified over the div, then a sudden break
text with link to source
then the text continues justified as normal
```

However, HTML code generated by the script is like this:

```
<div class="textDiv">Senior Advisor said in a <a href="test.html">media interview</a> that the overall monetary policy tone is shifting towards...</div>
```

Do you guys have any idea why this happens and how to fix it? So that the text is displayed smoothly without line breaks?

Comment: you have to do some changes in CSS file or code

Comment: What styles have you given to the `<a>` element?

Comment: Fixed it, thank you! it was in CSS, I had a general a {} style with display: block (for another section), added .textDiv a{display: inline;}, works now.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `htmlspecialchars_decode` all of the text's html is being decoded , so if you want to keep the decode function

1)Change the link in to how a normal link will look like , eg : yourwebsite.com/test.html don't add the  tag

2) Don't echo string directly  do this

```
$text = htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace("\r\n", "<br>", $row["textField"]);
```

3) Then pass the variable $text to code to detect links , here is one :-

```
        $reg_exUrl = '@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) {
    echo preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="https://'.$url[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);
    } 
    else 
    {
    echo $text;
    }
```

You can change the code to adjust to your needs